# want to access the widget's (here OneLineListItem) text and id when it is clicked using on_touch_down method

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

GOAL:

-call `my_callback()` function only if the `OneLineListItem` widget is pressed, other wise do nothing.

EXPLAIN THESE THINGS:

-Please explain how can i call the function `my_callback()` when any one of the `OneLineListItem` is pressed, using on_touch_down() function

-Also explain why we are adding `super(Touch, self).on_touch_down(touch)` in `else` block

PROBLEMS WITH THE CURRENT CODE:

-Do not give any error, but code does not working as i want.

-The `on_touch_down()` method is not working (wants to understand how it works, i have just copied it from the documentation of kivy).

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

helper_string = """
Screen:
    Touch:
    
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: containers    
"""

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        # createing the OneLineListItem
        item_1 = OneLineListItem(text='subject_1', id='item1')
        item_2 = OneLineListItem(text='subject_2', id='item2')
        item_3 = OneLineListItem(text='subject_3', id='item3')

        # adding the above OneLineListItem into MDList 
        self.root.ids.containers.add_widget(item_1)
        self.root.ids.containers.add_widget(item_2)
        self.root.ids.containers.add_widget(item_3)



class Touch(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        app = MDApp.get_running_app()

        # gets all the OneLineListItem in subject_wid_list
        subject_wid_list = app.root.ids.containers.children

        # plz explain this part briefly. have lots of confusion about .collide_point()
        # also explain why we are adding super(...).on_touch_down()
        # iterating in the list and checking for collision of widget with touched coordinates.

        for child in subject_wid_list:
            if child.collide_point(*touch.pos):
                print('touched one of the OneLineListItem widget')
                self.my_callback()

            else:
                print('touched something else other than OneLineListItem widget')
                return super(Touch, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def my_callback(self):
        pass

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You access the widget text and id through the instance:

```
  def mycallback(self,instance):
            m=instance.id 
            x=instnace.text
```

it determines the row and you can deal with it. You have to add id to the widget when you add it. I have not tried it with on_touch_down but I have with on_press and it worked.

You can call my_callback function when you add_widget as the following:

```
self.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text='as you want' ,id=str(i),halign="right",on_press=self.mycallback))
```